# Intersection of date ranges, calculation over all elements with an intersecting date range

Tags: datetime, pandas, grouping, intersection

The table below is representative of a larger table, ordered by Code (first column). For each id (4884, say), I'd like to identify the other ids with the same Code and that have a LOG_TIME that falls
 within the [start,finish] range (of id=4884, say). Then, among all those entries, I'd like to calculate the highest Price. Repeat this over 
all entries and enter the result as a highest Price new column.

In other words:

For each row in the data, calculate the highest price of all other entries 
in the table with the same Code and an overlapping [start,finish] range.

```
Code    finish         start          LOG_TIME       ID     Price
2   01/03/13 17:53  20/02/13 11:54  20/02/13 11:54  4884    80.5
2   01/03/13 17:53  20/02/13 11:54  26/02/13 10:06  4884    80.5
2   01/03/13 17:53  20/02/13 11:54  01/03/13 10:53  4884    85.1
2   01/03/13 17:53  20/02/13 11:54  01/03/13 17:53  4884    85.1
2   15/04/13 12:26  05/03/13 12:36  05/03/13 12:36  4961    86.25
2   15/04/13 12:26  05/03/13 12:36  08/03/13 11:11  4961    90.85
2   15/04/13 12:26  05/03/13 12:36  11/03/13 10:40  4961    92
2   15/04/13 12:26  05/03/13 12:36  15/04/13 12:26  4961    92
2   15/04/13 12:26  05/03/13 12:36  09/06/13 17:00  4961    92
2   26/06/13 10:55  26/06/13 10:55  26/06/13 10:55  5410    80.5
2   26/06/13 10:55  26/06/13 10:55  26/06/13 10:55  5410    80.5
3   01/01/14 22:50  18/12/13 15:46  18/12/13 15:46  6102    80.5
3   01/12/20 00:00  23/12/13 10:21  23/12/13 10:21  6114    81.65
3   01/01/14 22:50  18/12/13 15:46  01/01/14 22:50  6102    83.95
3   01/01/14 22:50  18/12/13 15:46  01/01/14 22:50  6102    83.95
….. ….  ….  ….  ….  ….
```

Is there a way of doing this efficiently over a large dataset? I can't see a way of doing it with dummy variables. Perhaps the only way is to do FOR loops over all the entries in a code for each entry, check whether the LOG_TIME falls within the range and then calculate the maximum price.

I wonder whether anyone can see a clever way of doing this. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you're using pandas and assuming the date are in datetime format, you can group by on 'code' and then apply a min, max function to that.

assuming df is your dataframe, you'll have something like this.

```
df.groupby('Code').apply(lambda x: min(x.LOG_TIME),max(x.LOG_TIME))
```

if LOG_TIME is not in datetime format, just convert it as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
df['LOG_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df.LOG_TIME)
```

Comment: How do you calculate the max price within that range after that?

Comment: If you only need the max price is easy as `df.groupby('Code')['price'].max()`

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the objective is, per row, to get the maximum price within a certain timeframe and within the code of the row. I don't think your code answers this